# Creating shortcut to folder in WIX that uses environmental variable

Tags: c#, wix

I'm trying to do two things in WIX:

- Create new environmental variable that points to specific directory, e.g. `%test%` which leads to a variable `[DOCUMENTSPATH]`
- Create a shortcut to that folder on the desktop. Shortcut must be using the same variable `[DOCUMENTSPATH]`

Using the `<RegistryKey>` and `<RegistryValue>` I can create the environmental variable that leads to variable.

```
<Component Id="EnvironmentAlias" Guid="827d993f-32c0-4088-a72a-43888a5f496a">
<RegistryKey  Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment">
<RegistryValue Type="string" Name="%NEW_PATH%" Value="[DOCUMENTSPATH]" Action="write"></RegistryValue>
</RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

This creates the shortcut

```
<Component Id="SampleDir" Guid="E9EAE95A-8234-406D-950D-397956287709"  Directory="DesktopFolder">
        <Shortcut Id="SampleDirSC" 
                  Name="somename" 
                  Target="[DOCUMENTSPATH]" 
                  Advertise="yes" 
                  Show="normal" />
</Component>
```

(Also tried with advertise=no)

The link and variable are created but the link type is file instead of folder - so both the behavior of it and looks are wrong. It looks like generic shortcut and does not open the folder on click - I need to `right-click -> go to location` to go to the `[DOCUMENTSPATH]` folder. This is because the `[DOCUMENTSPATH]` I'm using contains different environmental variable, e.g. %localappdata%.

Any ideas how to enforce target type of the shortcut in wix OR how to expand the environmental variables in wix?

Edit: additional explanation.
I am trying to make wix expand environmental variable (the one that starts with %, like %appdata%) when creating the shortcut because windows doesn't handle well dynamic variables in shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Change your  tag to this

```
<Component Id="SampleDir" Guid="E9EAE95A-8234-406D-950D-397956287709"  Directory="DesktopFolder">
        <Shortcut Id="SampleDirSC" 
                  Name="somename" 
                  Target="[DOCUMENTSPATH]" 
                  WorkingDirectory="DOCUMENTSPATH"
                  Show="normal" />
</Component>
```

This is a part sample of my test code

```
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortCutC" Guid="{CB93D6D1-AB98-4b45-98FF-4017EE5A0A09}">
        <Shortcut Id="AppShortCutC" Name="!(wix.Product)"
                  Description="!(wix.ProductDesc)"
                  Target="[INSTALLDIR]"
                  WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" />

        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="!(wix.Manufacturer)\!(wix.Product)" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
          <RegistryValue Name="ShortCutC" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"  />
        </RegistryKey>

        <RemoveFolder Id="ShortCutFolder" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>


      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef
```

Shortcut element [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/shortcut.html), says that advertise=yes ignores the target.

[Sample code](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html)

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I copied my tag mid-experimenting. I was experimenting if adding advertise=yes would help. This obviously does not fix my issue - I'll update the original question with more pictures in a second